# Connection pooling with Sailsjs

Tags: mysql, sails.js, connection-pooling

Since [there is not documentation about how to create connection poolings with Sailsjs](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/issues/546), I've being searching a little bit about it and I've found that [sails-mysql adapter](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql) do have any pooling configuration in it but is related to tests:

```
{
    host: process.env.WATERLINE_ADAPTER_TESTS_HOST || 'localhost',
    // (...)
    database: process.env.WATERLINE_ADAPTER_TESTS_DATABASE || 'sails_mysql',
    pool: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    waitForConnections: true
}
```

So I've tried to include `pool: true` to my `connections.js` file in Sails:

```
someMysqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    pool: true,
    database: 'mydatabase'
},
```

Server still runs and I recover data from the database but I'm not sure at all about if I have set connection throw a pooling service. Is there any way to check this feature?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try using the [`sails-mysql-transactions`](https://github.com/postmanlabs/sails-mysql-transactions) adapter. It has connection pooling, and you get transactions as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Everything is there in codes**

you can see the codes of sails-mysql(node modules) and you will find the solution for your doubts for sure.
in sails-mysql module the main js is `node-modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js` (according to `node-modules/sails-mysql/package.json`).
so in adapter.js file you can see..

```
/*--codes--*/
var _spawnConnection = require('./connections/spawn');
/*--codes--*/
defaults: {
  pool: true,
  connectionLimit: 5,
  waitForConnections: true
},
/*--codes--*/
```

which is setting for to use pool by default with connectionLimit 5.

Now go to the file `node-modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js` there
you see this snippet.

```
/*--codes--*/
/*--codes--*/
  if (connectionObject.connection.pool) {
    connectionObject.connection.pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
      afterwards(err, conn);
    });
    return;
  }

  // Use a new connection each time
  var conn = mysql.createConnection(connectionObject.config);
  conn.connect(function (err) {
    afterwards(err, conn);
  });
  return;
/*--codes--*/
/*--codes--*/
```

here it check if the adapter is set to use pool or not if it is `pool:true` then a connection is spawned from pool other wise a lone connection is used without pooling...

Now coming to your doubt....in your config/connections.js if u define an adapter like

```
mysqlServerMaster: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    pool: false,
    database: 'payments_db'
},
```

then you are using mysql without pooling.

and else If this setting you use...

```
mysqlServerMaster: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    pool: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    database: 'payments_db'
},
```

then you are having a mysql connection pool with connectioLimit ===10
for sure.
I hope you got it now.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-mysql